# Retrieving Columns with count greater than 1 - Google Sheet Query

Tags: sql, google-sheets, count, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google sheets, and I want to get the data from one sheet to another where I want **only** the columns with count > 1.

Let's say we have 3 columns A, B, and C. I tried the following (the first sheet name is "Form Responses 1"):

- I thought about using a query in the second sheet as: `=query('Form Responses 1'!A1:Z, "Select A having count (A) >1 union select B having count (B) >1 union select C having count (C) > 1")`. But I got a parse error where it seems that union and having are not supported in google sheets query.

How can I achieve this (whether it's using query or any other Google sheets function that can work)?

**More details:**

The first sheet contains info about exercises conducted during a lecture and it gets its data from a Google Form (so the responses are fed in this sheet). Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]
**Please note** that the form is divided into sections. When the user selects the course, the attendance, the participation, and adds a comment, then they go to the next section, the next section will be **based on the selected course**, the newly opened section will have the exercise name and rating questions (the exercise name is a dropdown list with items that are prefilled and specific to the selected course). That's why, you can see that "exercise name" and "rate the exercise" columns are repeated because we have 2 sections in this form.

The second sheet should contain the data of a selected course only (either mobile dev or web dev) which can be achieved easily through a query with a where clause. But, in addition to that, it shouldn't contain the empty columns of "exercise name" and "rate the exercise" as they correspond to another section. So, it should have only one exercise name column and one rating column that correspond to the selected course. Here is a screenshot if we only use a query with where clause without removing the extra name and rating columns:

[image]

Here is a screenshot with the desired result:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

why not use just:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A1:Z, "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G where F is not null", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "OR" condition

Eg:-

QUERY(Data!A:R,"select A, N, P where N>0 or P>0")

where A column has country and N, P columns have population values